# This does not work in excel online

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-indirect

I'm trying to make this formula work in excel online. When offline it works perfectly. I'm using excel 2013 and tried to use Chrom, Firefox and explorer with it. I saw in some place that the reason is the "#" but have no idea how to fix this.

> =HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",INDIRECT("trit!D"&ROW())), 0)

Any idea?

Comment: That is considered a 'relative hyperlink'. From [Using hyperlinks in a workbook in the browser](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-hyperlinks-in-a-workbook-in-the-browser-abc4e340-0cf1-426e-9a69-20531b0c9a5f) - "Workbooks in the browser only support absolute hyperlinks, or hyperlinks that contain a full address. This includes the protocol, the Web Server, the path, and the file name. They do not support relative hyperlinks, which contain only part of a full address. In contrast, Excel supports both absolute hyperlinks and relative hyperlinks."

Comment: Thank you, how can I insert masive amount of absolute hyperlink?